# MySQL / PHP: push whole row into associative array, _without_ naming each cell

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am looking for a programming shortcut. I want to push the entire row into an associative array, the $key being the same as the column name, and the $value being the value in that particular column, and all that, one row at a time.

So far, the only way I know how to do something like this is:

```
$array = [];
$push_item = [];

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
     $column_name_1 = $row['column_name_1'];
     $column_name_2 = $row['column_name_2'];
     //etc.

   $push_item = ["column_name_1" => $column_name_1, "column_name_2" => $column_name_2, ];
   array_push($array, $push_item);
}
```

And like that, for every row in the table.

I am looking for a solution that will go easier on my typing. Can I grab the column names and data automatically?

Thank you.

Comment: `$row` already contains the associative array, you could just assign `$row` to `$array[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself:

The function that does this is $mysqli->fetch_array();